# Differentiable dependence on initial conditions and parameters of an ODE

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, initial-value-problems

I don't know what equations they want me to found here:

> Let $\phi(t,t_0,x_0,(a,b))$ be the solution to the IVP
>
> $$\begin{cases}\dot{x}=2t(ax-bx^2) \\x(t_0)=x_0\end{cases}$$
>
> Prove that the derivatives $\partial\phi_{x_0}(t,0,1,(1,0))$, $\ \partial\phi_{a}(t,0,1,(1,0))$, $\ \partial\phi_{b}(t,0,1,(1,0))$ are the same that the ones we obtain using the differentiable dependence theorem on initial conditions and parameters.

I know how to solve this system and how to find $\partial\phi_{x_0}(t,0,1,(1,0))$, $\ \partial\phi_{a}(t,0,1,(1,0))$ and $\ \partial\phi_{b}(t,0,1,(1,0))$, but I don't know what they me to obtain using the differentiable dependence theorem on initial conditions and parameters.

I'd appreciate some hint about it.

Thanks.